# ImportError with cythonized Python code on Spark Standalone Job using Azure Machine Learning Studio

Tags: python, apache-spark, cython, azure-machine-learning-service, cythonize

I have cythonized my code and built an egg from it successfully. If I install the egg locally and import functions from the module, it works. However, when I deploy the egg file to a Spark Standalone Job on Azure Machine Learning Studio, I get an import error as follows.

> ImportError: cannot import name 'get_random' from 'mylib.foo' (/home/trusted-service-user/.cache/Python-Eggs/mylib.egg-tmp/mylib/foo.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)

My project that I am testing is very simple, I have a single file `./mylib/foo.py` and it looks like the following. Also there is this file `./mylib/__init__.py` and it is empty.

```py
import random

def get_random():
    return random.randint(0, 100)
```

To build the package I simply type in the following.

```bash
python setup.py bdist_egg sdist bdist_wheel
```

I get 3 artifacts in `./dist`.

- mylib-0.0.1-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl
- mylib-0.0.1-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg
- mylib-0.0.1.tar.gz

My `setup.py` file is unremarkable and looks like the following.

```py
import shutil
from pathlib import Path

from Cython.Build import cythonize
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.extension import Extension

with open('README.md', 'r') as fh:
    long_desc = fh.read()


class CustomBuildExt(build_ext):
    def run(self):
        build_ext.run(self)

        build_dir = Path(self.build_lib)
        root_dir = Path(__file__).parent

        target_dir = build_dir if not self.inplace else root_dir

        self.copy_file(Path('mylib') / '__init__.py', root_dir, target_dir)

    def copy_file(self, path, source_dir, destination_dir):
        if not (source_dir / path).exists():
            return

        shutil.copyfile(str(source_dir / path), str(destination_dir / path))


setup(
    packages=[],
    ext_modules=cythonize(
        module_list=[Extension('mylib.*', ['mylib/**/*.py'])],
        build_dir='build',
        compiler_directives={
            'always_allow_keywords': False,
            'language_level': 3
        }
    ),
    cmdclass={
        'build_ext': CustomBuildExt
    }
)
```

I then create a Spark Standalone Job using Azure CLI as follows.

```bash
az ml job create \
    -f thejob.yaml \
    -g [resource_group] \
    -w [workspace_name] \
    --subscription [subscription_id]
```

The `thejob.yaml` looks like the following.

```yaml
$schema: http://azureml/sdk-2-0/SparkJob.json
type: spark

code: ./src
entry:
  file: thejob.py

py_files:
  - mylib-0.0.1-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg

conf:
  spark.driver.cores: 1
  spark.driver.memory: 2g
  spark.executor.cores: 2
  spark.executor.memory: 2g
  spark.executor.instances: 2

inputs:
  input_data:
    type: uri_file
    path: [some_abfss_file_path]
    mode: direct

args: >-
  --input_data ${{inputs.input_data}}

identity:
  type: user_identity

resources:
  instance_type: standard_e4s_v3
  runtime_version: "3.2"
```

The job is created and executes until the import statement, which then fails from the `ImportError`. Anyone have a clue why this is happening with my cythonized code?

When I use the non-cythonized code (different branch, the main one), the import works and the job finishes to completion successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the scenario, it is possible that the egg file is not being deployed to the correct location on the Spark Standalone Job. You can try to specify the path to the egg file in the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable in the Spark Standalone Job configuration.
As per the documentation [Submit Spark jobs in Azure Machine Learning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-submit-spark-jobs?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=cli) in the YAML properties in the Spark job specification :

```
`py_files` - defines a list of `.zip`, `.egg`, or `.py` files, to be placed in the `PYTHONPATH`, for successful execution of the job.
```

Here are the steps on how to place a .egg file in the PYTHONPATH:

1. **Find the location of the .egg file.**  The .egg file is a zip file that contains a Python package.
2. **Add the directory containing the .egg file to the PYTHONPATH.**  The PYTHONPATH is an environment variable that tells Python where to find Python packages. You can add the directory containing the .egg file to the PYTHONPATH by running the following command:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$directory_containing_the_egg_file
```

For details on related to package installation please refer to [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-python-package-installation.md) documentation.

Another possibility is that the egg file was not built correctly. You can try to rebuild the egg file and ensure that it is built for the correct platform. For this you can also check if **the Python version on the Spark Standalone Job matches the Python version used to build the egg file.** If the Python versions are different, it can cause import errors.